# Trying to change code from accepting 3 command line arguments to accept in one command line argument that splits date in a .txt file provided

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, split

I have code that accepts in 3 command line arguments from the user ie.

java Project2 12 10 1995

and manipulates a .txt file to check if the date is valid and then returns that date's specific day if it's valid. I'm trying to change it so it will accept only 1 command line argument ie.

java Project2 12/10/1995

and it will do the same function in returning the specific day if valid but I don't know how to change it so it can accept 1 argument and splits it at the "/" and then checks the .txt file and sees if it then, is valid.

Code: http://pastebin.com/i5cQV0KS

.txt file: http://pastebin.ca/2662759

Comment: You could just put the code in the post :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use code like:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(args[0]);
sc.useDelimiter("/");
int day = sc.nextInt();
int month = sc.nextInt();
int year = sc.nextInt();
```